# how to find out the directory of the installerplugin while installation in mac

Tags: macos, installation, pkg-file

I have created an installer plugin which would show a pane while installing the pkg file from a GUI. I need to know the location of the executable of the installerplugin run when the installation takes place, so that I could access a file relative to that path. The NSProcessInfo class is of no help as the process it refers to is the installer.app. Is there some way to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the way. We can use the `NSBundle` Class to locate the bundle by:

```
NSBundle* iPlugin = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[MyInstallerPlugin class]];
```

and then using

```
[iPlugin bundlePath ];
```

we can find the absolute path of the root of the bundle.